# Expression statement to cover all exceptions in catch exception strategy in mule?

Tags: exception, mule

I have scenario like if 3 errors occurs then one catch block should execute other than these three other catch block should execute.

I have tried by placing 3 exceptions : #[exception.causedBy(java.net.UnknownHostException) ||exception.causedBy(java.net.ConnectException)||exception.causedBy(org.mule.transport.jms.redelivery.MessageRedeliveredException)] in first catch-1 when condition and left second catch as blank. But what issue I'm facing here is control is directly entering into second catch-2. I have tried by pacing #[exception.causedBy(*)] in second catch-2. But it didn't work can anybody suggest on this?
Thanks.,

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the exception being thrown is not any of those exceptions so it will enter the second catch. If you want to catch all exceptions, dont add a 'when' attribute or just use a catch-exception-strategy or maybe #[exception.causedBy(java.lang.Exception)]